# How do I change desktop background with a terminal command?

Tags: macos, desktop

I'm trying to add to my OS X configuration script a command which sets the background to the plain dark grey, however, when applied, it only sets it to the main monitor and any additional monitors currently connected keep their current background and any added thereafter still receive the default space background. What I have so far is as follows:

> # Change Desktop default BackgroundColor to grey
>   defaults write com.apple.desktop '{ Background = { default = {BackgroundColor = ( "0.25490197

How do I set the default the the dark grey background via a terminal command? How do I change all monitors already configured to grey via a terminal command?

Comment: Everything you need should be here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40644/how-do-i-change-desktop-background-with-a-terminal-command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the Applescript commands you could use

```
set localLibrary to path to library folder from local domain as string
set desktopImage to localLibrary & "Desktop Pictures:Solid Colors:Solid Gray Dark.png" as alias
tell application "Finder" set desktop picture to desktopImage end tell
```

You can easily turn any of the above Applescripts into a terminal command using `osascript [-e statement]`:

```
osascript -e 'set desktopImage to POSIX file "/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Solid Gray Light.png"tell application "Finder"
set desktop picture to desktopImage
end tell'
```

Comment: Can you walk through the script, to make it a little easier for visitors to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `osascript` on macOS Monterey 12.4 to set the picture on every desktop such as:

```
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell every desktop to set picture to \"/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Stone.png\" as POSIX file"
```

To find preinstalled desktop pictures for macOS Monterey:

```
find '/System/Library/Desktop Pictures' -not -path '*/.*'
```

To find preinstalled desktop pictures for macOS Big Sur:

```
find '/Library/Desktop Pictures' -not -path '*/.*'
```

If you prefer to make a script that's easier to read:

```
file="/System/Library/Desktop Pictures/Solid Colors/Stone.png"
osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to tell every desktop to set picture to \"${file}\" as POSIX file"
```